# Energy Chamber and Armageddon Clock

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Can [Energy Chamber](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bEnergy%20Chamber%5d) be used with [Armageddon Clock](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bArmageddon%20Clock%5d)? I.e. are the counters on Armageddon Clock "charge counters"?

Answer (score 5):

**No, putting counters on [Armageddon Clock](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bArmageddon%20Clock%5d) with [Energy Chamber](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bEnergy%20Chamber%5d) will not allow you to deal damage with Armageddon Clock.**

Energy Chamber's ability places "Charge Counters" onto Artifacts, whereas Armageddon Clock's ability instructs you to deal damage equal to the number of "Doom Counters" on it. While you can combine counters with the same name, counters of different names are not interchangeable.

> **121.1.** A counter is a marker placed on an object or player that modifies its characteristics and/or interacts with a rule, ability, or effect. Counters are not objects and have no characteristics. Notably, a counter is not a token, and a token is not a counter. Counters with the same name or description are interchangeable.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the other answers, Armageddon Clock's abilities refer to doom counters, not charge counters, so Energy Chamber won't help with it.  However, here are some cards that will:

- [Doubling Season](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDoubling%20Season%5d)
- [Clockspinning](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bClockspinning%5d) (provided the clock has at least one doom counter)
- [Gilder Bairn](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGilder%20Bairn%5d) (provided the clock has at least one doom counter)
- [Vorel of the Hull Clade](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bVorel%20of%20the%20Hull%20Clade%5d) (provided the clock has at least one doom counter)
- [Anything with Proliferate](https://scryfall.com/search?q=o%3Aproliferate) (provided the clock has at least one doom counter)
- [Eye Of Doom](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bEye%20Of%20Doom%5d) (can add a doom counter every time it enters the battlefield; just don't activate it's ability unless the clock has no counters)
- [Imminent Doom](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bImminent%20Doom%5d) + [Opalescence](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bOpalescence%5d) + [March of the Machines](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMarch%20of%20the%20Machines%5d) + [Fate Transfer](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bFate%20Transfer%5d) (okay, this one is a bit impractical)
- [Giant Fan](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGiant%20Fan%5d) and [Everythingamajig](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bEverythingamajig%5d) (not legal in most formats)

Comment: And, of course, Doubling Season.

Comment: @Zags anything with proliferate like Atraxa...

Answer (score 2):

No. Energy Chamber refers to "charge counters"; Armageddon Clock works with "doom counters". On some forms of the card, like the autolinked one, you can't see that since it just referred to "counters". Later printings, such as the [Fourth Edition one](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=2018), do indicate the difference. As always, the Gatherer will tell you the current Oracle ("official") text:

> At the beginning of your upkeep, put a doom counter on Armageddon Clock.
>
> At the beginning of your draw step, Armageddon Clock deals damage equal to the number of doom counters on it to each player.
>
> {4}: Remove a doom counter from Armageddon Clock. Any player may activate this ability but only during any upkeep step.

Of course, you *can* put a charge counter on Armageddon Clock with Energy Chamber; it just won't have the effect you probably want it to have.